# How do I get list of observers from a Subject in C#

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a Subject (System.Reactive.Subjects) to which I subscribe multiple observers. Is it possible to get the list of observers from this subject?

Basically I need to copy the observers from Subject A to Subject B.

```
var newSubject = new Subject();
if (oldSubject.HasObservers)
{
    var observers = oldSubject. <-- not quite sure what to do here.
    foreach(var obs in observers)
    {
        newSubject.Subscribe(obs);
    }
}
```

**Update1 - Why do I need to do this**

Another library that I have no control over calls onCompleted to oldSubject. And then they will make another call asking for the subject. If I return the oldSubject, all the observers that have subscribed for updates will no longer get updates. So, I am looking at creating a new Subject, sticking the active observers on to it, and then returning this new subject.

**Update2 - Full context of problem with sample code**

I am using a library that exposes an Observable. However, this observable only accepts a single observer (Please do not ask me why and how, this is information I cannot discuss in a public forum). So, I am writing a layer of Observable (using Subject) that would allow for multiple observers to subscribe for updates.

The single observer that I am passing to the other library is as follows:

```
public class DataObserver<T> : IObserver<IList<ChangeEvent<T>>>
{
    public DataObserver(string id, Subject<Tuple<string, IList<ChangeEvent<T>>>> subject)
    {
        Id = id;
        Subject = subject;
    }

    public Subject<Tuple<string, IList<ChangeEvent<T>>>> Subject { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        Subject?.OnCompleted();
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        Subject?.OnError(error);
    }

    public void OnNext(IList<ChangeEvent<T>> value)
    {
        Subject?.OnNext(new Tuple<string, IList<ChangeEvent<T>>>(Id, value));
    }
}
```

Now the other library gets this observer via the TryGetObserver method in the MySingletonClass below:

```
public MySingletonClass 
{
    public MySingletonClass() 
    {
        DataObservables = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<Type, dynamic>>();
    }   

    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<Type, dynamic>> DataObservables { get; set; }

    public (bool Success, IObserver<IList<ChangeEvent<T>>> Observer) TryGetObserver<T>(string id)
    {
        var dataSubject = new Subject<Tuple<string, IList<ChangeEvent<T>>>>();
        var dataObserver = new DataObserver<T>(id, dataSubject);
        var hasObserver = DataObservables.ContainsKey(id);
        if (hasObserver)
        {
            var val = DataObservables[id];
            if (val.Item2 is DataObserver<T> extantObserver && extantObserver.Subject.HasObservers)
            {
                // var observers = extantObserver.Subject. <-- This is not going to work.
                // foreach(var obs in observers)
                // {
                //    dataObserver.Subject.Subscribe(obs);
                // }
            }
        }

        DataObservables.TryAdd(id, new Tuple<Type, dynamic>(typeof(T), dataObserver));

        return (true, dataObserver);
    }
}
```

So, the other library will call TryGetObserver the first time and I will return the correct object. Then it will call onCompleted off of the Subject in that object at some point. Subsequently, it will call TryGetObserver again, and now I have to return a new Subject with all the previously subscribed observers.

Comment: You can't do this unless you make your own decorator subject and keep track of the observers yourself. But why do you need to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to copy the observers? They will have an active subscription to your original subject and they will not automatically gain a second one to the new subject. What are you trying to do? Please edit your question for the explanation.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks. Looking at making a wrapper Subject class.

Comment: @Manas - Don't wrap the subject - it won't work for you. Any observer that got an `OnCompleted` will not accept anymore values as the subscription has ended. It's like as though `.Dispose()` has been called on the subscription once an `OnCompleted` is called. You need to work out another method to get the behaviour you need.

Comment: @Manas - You need to describe the actual behaviour that you need. Then maybe we can help.

Comment: @Manas - Can you show us a [mcve] of your code and how the 3rd party code is calling `.onCompleted`?

Comment: @Enigmativity, standby. Working on it.

Comment: @Enigmativity, added details and relevant code example.

Comment: Why do you generate a new `DataObserver` object each time you call `TryGetObserver`? Try to keep this `DataObject` object alive and let your other subscribers join/left as they like. Then you don't need to move they existing subscribers to the new object, you just return still the old still active `DataObserver` object.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by:

- Creating a custom Subject which wrapped around the native Subject.
- Not calling subject.OnCompleted when OnCompleted was called (refer to problem description above). Instead I used my own custom tracker to do the needful when the stream was marked as completed. This ensured that the subscribed observers were not signaled that the stream was stopped, and I could reuse them. As it turns out, since the framework marks a private member isStopped (on each observer) as 1, whenever OnCompleted is called on the observable, the original idea of copying observers would never have worked.

This is not ideal, but for the purposes of our software, it is an acceptable solution.